# Errors with Static Table Views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Trying to work out a couple of scenes in my app my I cant get the tableViews to work as they should.

Im doing a settings like **tableView** where the user choses between **two possible settings**. Each options leads to **new tableView where the user must pick one of the available options**. Once the user has chosen one, the label in the first scene will display the value chosen (which is stored also as NSUserDefaults). So if Im not mistaken this could be achieved with 3 static tableViews. The code following is how Im trying to do it:

Initial settings view controller:

```
class SettingsVC2: UITableViewController{
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("office_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Select your office"
        return cell
}
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dept_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Select your department"
        return cell
   }
```

One of the settings tableViews:

```
class SettingsDepartmentTVC: UITableViewController{

let departamentos: [String] = ["Sales", "Pre-Sales", "General Administration", "Customer Service", "Profesional Services", "Regionales"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return departamentos.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("department_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.departamentos[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
}
```

I believe all datasources and delegates are hooked right and UIKit is imported even if not shown.

Erros Im getting:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier office_cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

---

This is the method where I try to populate the tableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell{


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentsRowTVC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentsRowTVC

    let single_comment = self.AOS[indexPath.row]

    cell.titulo_comentario?.text = single_comment.titulo_comment
        cell.cuerpo_comentario?.text = single_comment.cuerpo_comment
    cell.fecha_comentario?.text = single_comment.fecha_comment
    return cell
}

class CommentsRowTVC: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var titulo_comentario: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cuerpo_comentario: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var fecha_comentario: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Here is the connections inspector for the UIViewController where the table is:

[image: Outlets]

And this one for the UIViewCellController:

[image: Outlets2]

Errors to this point:

> UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: [UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: can you add a storyBoard screenshot?

Comment: did you added the indentifier to your storyboard?

Comment: @PabloDuque you should set a breakpoint and try stepping through your code, see where it breaks and report back

Comment: It has to be something in the Storyboard since the error has nothing to do with the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Or if it is related to that method is related to the IDs or identifiers. I edited the answer adding the UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're truly making **static** table view cells then you should just delete these methods. You only use them when you are dequeueing cells dynamically.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return departamentos.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("department_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.departamentos[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

If you are actually trying to make **dynamic cells** then, as your error message suggests, you need to make sure your identifier matches what you have in interface builder:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("{your_identifier}", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.departamentos[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

Comment: How do I add content to the cells then?

Comment: If you're making static cells you do it in the storyboard. Just drag labels out and name them what you want. "Static" means they never change, so just dragging labels out will do the trick but only if you remove the methods I mentioned.

Comment: Alright, I see. What about the table view which labels show whats stored in the NSUserDefautls? Would be something like what I was trying to do work?

Comment: Yes, just drag an outlet from each static cell into your tableViewController and pull your values from your NSUserDefaults and set them to your labels in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Okey thank you! I will try both things and get back to you when Im done! :)

Comment: The dynamic table Im using has 3 labels. Im getting error both ways but should I create a cellViewController where I hook the labels and then create an object of that cellViewController in the mtehod cellForRowAtIndexPath on the tableviewcontroller. Or should I hook directly the labels to the tableviewcontroller? or something different? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know the error Im gettings is the following:
**unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Comment: @PabloDuque I've updated my answer based on your error. The error stems from a few different things but what I've listed above is the most common one.

Comment: I checked what you said and everything seems to be fine to my understanding. Im going to edit the question adding more information because I think Im not giving you all you need to be able to answer. Thanks

Comment: @PabloDuque It could be many things, you can either use GitHub Gists to post more of your code or you could just dropbox your project to me. I don't mind taking a look.

Comment: Thats really nice of you. But I just started this app and there is not much more code to show (at least no in this class).

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have provided it looks like you have not registered your table view cells and identifiers with the table view.

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

> Discussion Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the
>   registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view how
>   to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently
>   in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to
>   create a new cell object automatically.
>
> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
>   identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces
>   the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to
>   unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

I would suggest that you register them in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
    let KDepartmentCellIdentifier = "department_cell"
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.class, forCellReuseIdentifier: kKDepartmentCellIdentifier)

    let KOfficeCellIdentifier = "office_cell"
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.class, forCellReuseIdentifier: kOfficeCellIdentifier)
```

If you are using a nib then use

```
registerNib(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```